How can I get a Pointer to a generic instance?
  TTestClass = class
    content: Integer;
  end;

  TTest = class
    public
      class procedure TestProc<T: class>(obj: T);
  end;

class procedure TTest.TestProc<T>(obj: T);
var
  p: Pointer;
begin
  p := Pointer(obj);
  p := @obj;
end;

Here, the two different ways of getting a pointer to an object give different results. RTTI functions take the first method, but it only works for classes. So how can I get an instance of Pointer for any generic variable (ie replace T: class by just T) ? And why is the actual pointer different ?

Pointer(obj) type-casts the value of obj into a Pointer, whereas @obj gives you the memory address of obj itself. Hence you will always get 2 different addresses.
A class object is a reference type, it is passed around by pointer.
When you have the obj parameter constrained with the class Generic attribute, you are forcing obj to be an object pointer. So its value will point at the object, and @obj will be the address of the parameter itself, not the object it is pointing at.
When obj is not constrained then it can be any type, it's not guaranteed to be a pointer at all.  If it is a value type (like an integer, etc) instead of a reference type (like an object), you will have to pass it in as a var parameter in order to use @obj to get the address of the caller's original variable.

Making obj a var parameter does not fix the issue, @obj and Pointer(obj) still return different values.

@JohnJohn @obj versus Pointer(obj) will always have different values, since @ is a reference and Type() is a cast - both are different things. Always.

Ah, so Pointer isn't just an Integer value representing an address ? Indeed that would be the culprit here.
Unfortunately I'm investigating this for use in RTTI, and RTTI functions take Pointer instances. And Pointer(AGenericVariable) is not a valid cast. Using @ on classes doesn't work for RTTI.

@JohnJohn A pointer IS an integer representing an address. But without the class constraint, your obj MAY or MAY NOT be a pointer type. Which RTTI functions exactly are you having trouble with, and how are you trying to use them? Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that doesn't work for you, so someone can give you a better answer of how to solve it properly. You will likely have to resort to using a var parameter and RTTI to detect if T is a pointer type or not, and then act on obj accordingly.

@RemyLebeau I can check the TRTTIType to know if my obj is an instance (thus making Pointer(obj) possible), but I don't know how to tell the compiler that it is. And if it doesn't know, it won't compile because of the invalid typecast.

@JohnJohn again, please update your question with the actual code you are struggling with so myself or someone else can help you make it work the way you want.

The first method – Pointer(obj) – is just a cast, and "does" nothing. It just takes the variable obj and looks at it as if it were a pointer. This happens to work for classes, because such variables actually do hold pointers.
The second method – @obj – actually does something: it creates a pointer to the variable. This works for all types of variables.
A problem with the second method might be that the parameter (obj) is passed by value, not by reference, so @obj gives you a pointer to the local variable obj, and not to the original variable that was passed as argument to TestProc. To make @obj point to the original variable passed as argument to TTestProc, add the var keyword:
class procedure TestProc<T>(var obj: T);


This is not correct. Instances are passed by reference, so by your reasoning both values should be the same, which they aren't.

@JohnJohn: No - POINTER(Intf) returns the address that Intf POINTS TO, where #Intf returns the address OF Intf. (# should be an "at" sign, but I can't enter it as such - it tries to do a user lookup when I do)

@HeartWare Welcome to Markdown - as far as Stack Overflow's comment formatting help doesn't give you the idea to simply use backticks for code in general (and then @Intf wouldn't refer to a user) see the Markdown help in general to learn about backslashes to escape characters, so writing \@ (without backticks) would result in @ alone.

@AmigoJack: Thanks - I'll try to remember that next time I need to escape a character...
